# "Using" an out parameter

Tags: c#

Let's imagine I have a simple class that is disposable:

```
class CanDispose : IDisposable
{
   ...
}
```

Now I can obviously put this in a "using" block to make it dispose:

```
using (var myDisposable = new CanDispose())
{
    ...
}
```

But what if I have a factory method that returns the disposable via an out parameter? In my example there can be multiple returns, so multiple outs are clean:

```
public bool CreateDisposable(out CanDispose canDispose)
{
   canDispose = new CanDispose();
   ...
   return ret; 
}
```

How do I put this in a using statement? Simply putting the function call into a using block doesn't seem to work. Do I have to resort to returning a Tuple (will that work?), or is there a simpler way?

Note, this doesn't appear to work. At least it doesn't shut up the warning about disposing before going out of scope:

```
using (CreateDisposable(out CanDispose myDispose))
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: The `CreateDisposable` method needs to return a `bool`...

Comment: @RufusL, I added an indicative line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `using` statement doesn't *have* to declare a variable.  Having a disposable as an `out` paramter is not ideal, and you should avoid it in your own code, but if you're consuming a library that does it, you can simply put the variable in the `using` block's expression after calling the method.

```cs
CreateDisposable(out CanDispose myDispose);
using (myDispose)
{
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> How do I put this in a using statement?

You do not.  Those two patterns -- out parameter, and automatic dispose via `using` -- do not compose well.

> Do I have to resort to returning a Tuple (will that work?)

I note that questions of the form "will this work?" can be answered by trying it. But to save you those keystrokes: tuples are not disposable.

> is there a simpler way?

Just use a `using` block on the `out` parameter; make it two statements, not one.

But your question indicates that there is a more fundamental problem here. Presumably the Boolean that is returned is meaningful. It sounds like you are planning on ignoring that Boolean and `using` the out parameter regardless; if that is safe to do, then just make a version that returns the value without the Boolean, since it is apparently not useful.

More generally -- the fact that you are returning two values from a factory is a code smell. Can you say more about what you are doing? There might be a better pattern to use altogether.

Comment: The reason for the multiple returns is that I am returning accessors to database tables, where they all share the same database context. I could create the context and then pass it in to different factories, but that disassociates the two things, which makes it more error-prone.

Comment: @SimonParker: If the two things are tightly bound then you might make a disposable class that encapsulates those two things, and return that.

Comment: As usual, things are never simple. The factory is a generic factory that can generate different accessors depending on which is requested. This means returning a single disposable would require some form of magic to get the right accessor out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Put your using on the next line

```
CreateDisposable(out CanDispose myDispose);
using (myDispose)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare it first and then use it on the `using` statement.

```
CreateDisposable(out CanDispose myDispose)
using (myDispose)
{
    ....
}
```

You can look into this links to get more information about `using`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/the-using-statement-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 1):

Since`using` statement is just an implementation of 'try / finally' statement, so you can just use this statement directly as the following:

```
   CanDispose canDispose = null;
        try
        {
            CreateDisposable(out CanDispose canDispose);
        }

        finally
        {
            canDispose?.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping your factory method with an adapter will let you keep the semantics that you're used to. Consistency is generally a Good Thing™

```
public void SomeFunction()
{
  var getInstance = () => {
    CreateDisposable( out CanDispose instance );
    return instance;
  };

  using ( var instance = getInstance() ) {
    // do something with your instance before it gets disposed.
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you need multiple results

My suggestion is to use a `Tuple`, but it looks like you want to know if the object was created successfully, so you may want to be checking the results. In any case, using the `out` is going to require you to define the var on a different line.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var factory = new DisposableFactory();
        IDisposable d;
        var success = factory.TryGetDisposable(out d);
        if (success){
            using (d) {

            }           
        }   

        using (factory.GetDisposableResults().Item2){

        }
    }   
}

public class CanDispose : IDisposable
{
    void IDisposable.Dispose(){

    }
}

public class DisposableFactory
{
    public bool TryGetDisposable(out IDisposable d)
    {
        d = new CanDispose();
        return true;
    }

    public (bool, IDisposable) GetDisposableResults()
    {
        var tup = (true, new CanDispose());
        return tup;
    }
}
```